# dedicated mouse buttons on lenovo x1 carbon

Tags: xfce, thinkpad

Is there any way that one could assign the dedicated mouse buttons on a thinkpad to be something else than mouse-clicks? What I'm aiming towards is to assigned each of them to toggle through workspaces in xfce4...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first problem is identifying them. A typical laptop presents its trackpoint and touchpad as two different mice, but sometimes they do not associate the buttons with the device you expect. For example one laptop had all four buttons associated with the touchpad (which reported having two buttons), and none with the trackpoint (which also reported having two buttons). as you can guess this made it difficult to use the trackpoint when the touchpad was disabled (which was something I liked to do as it was positioned where I kept hitting it by mistake). You can check this by exclusively opening the event device associated with each mouse (which prevents it from forwarding events to the main composite mouse device. You can get more information on this by reading the documentation on the event devices, which you want to do because the next step is to write an event responder.

The event responder that you would then write would recognise the button presses and then do something. I recommend starting with beep. Nice and simple and you can get it working without reading the documentation on your window manager, which may make the rest of this look easy. Good Luck.